# Duality discrete math problem

Tags: propositional-calculus

This is the only answer I got wrong on my HW and the prof does not want to give us the correct answers before our midterm

> The dual of a compound proposition that contains only the logical operators $\lor$ , $\land$ , and
>   $\neg$ is the compound proposition obtained by replacing each $\lor$ by $\land$ , each $\land$ by $\lor$ , each $\def\T{{\rm T}}\def\F{{\rm F}}$
>   $\T$ by $\F$ , and each $\F$ by $\T$ . The dual of $s$ is denoted by $s^*$. Find the dual of these compound propositions.
>
> a) $p \lor\neg q$

I got $\neg p \land q$

> b) $p \land (q \lor (r \land \T))$

My answer was $\neg p \lor (\neg q \land r)$

> c) $(p \land \neg q) \lor (q \land \F)$

My answer was $(\neg p \lor q) \land  \neg q$

I have tried googling the problem and cannot come up with anything on duals and our lectures are online and upon reviewing do not see anything. I am just confused and looking for a little guidance on what was incorrect with my answers.

Comment: This can't be "easy" if you didn't get it right. How about a slightly more descriptive title instead?

Comment: Sorry about the misleading title. When I first did it I thought it was very simple and now that I see the answer it was just a simple mistake on my part.

Answer (score 3):

When I first looked that this problem in Rosens, *Discrete Mathematics and Its Applications*, I was very confused. After a computer driven CTRL-F search, the word dual seemed to only be in the book twice. They Explain what a dual is inside the problem. If you're this far along in the assignment, then the real problem for the 3 part question is the way the word the question.

"The **dual** of a compound proposition that contains only the
logical operators ∨, ∧, and ¬ is the compound proposition
**obtained by replacing each ∨ by ∧, each ∧ by ∨, each T
by F, and each F by T**. The dual of s is denoted by s
∗."

The wording makes it seem as though the dual of an equation is found by switching

- V to ∧
- ∧ to V
- T to F
- F to T
- ¬q to q

but really, its just

- V to ∧
- ∧ to V
- T to F
- F to T

No need for changing the negations

They included the  "extra" information on the negation because you can only find the dual of problems containing those symbols. So a problem containing a bi-conditional would not work. As far as we know this far in the book.

Answer (score 3):

What you have done is wrong. **Why you have negated all the proposition and the then find the dual?**

**Like dual of (p ∧ ¬q) is (p ∨ ¬q) not (¬p ∨ q).**

Here is the definition of dual of a compound proposition:

**The dual of a compound proposition that contains only the logical operators ∨, ∧, and ¬ is the compound proposition obtained by replacing each ∨ by ∧, each ∧ by ∨, each T by F, and each F by T. The dual of s is denoted by s∗.** *(Reference: Discrete Mathematics (7th Edition) Kenneth H. Rosen)*

Example:
S =(p ∧ q)∨ (¬p ∨ q)∨ F

dual of S = (p ∨ q)∧ (¬p ∧ q)∧T

So the correct answer to your question is:

a) p∨¬q

dual: p∧¬q

b) p∧(q∨(r∧T))

dual: p∨(q∧(r∨F))

c) (p∧¬q)∨(q∧F)

dual: (p∨¬q)∧(q∨T)

Comment: Fairly new to discrete math here, so there's a very real chance I'm wrong, but c can be shortened. `(q or T)` is a tautology, so it's always T. That leaves `(p or not q) and T`, which is just `p or not q` because `T` has no actual impact on the answer

Answer (score 0):

To obtain the dual of a formula , replace ∧ with V and T with F vice versa..
eg: dual of pVq is p∧q it is not ¬p∧¬q
reference: Discrete mathematical structures with applications to computer science by J.P Tremblay and R.Manohar.