# Dual of Propositional Formula

Tags: propositional-calculus

I have a question regarding an older question on StackExchange, because the answers are confusing me.

[Duality discrete math problem](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/529611/duality-discrete-math-problem)

How do I create the dual of a term?

1) `A = A and B` , `Ad = A or B`

2) `A = A and B` , `Ad = not A or not B`

Comment: 2nd one: change "and" with "or" and vice versa and every prop letter with its negation. It is explained in the [answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/529611/duality-discrete-math-problem).

Comment: Yes, Thank you. The answers of that link were confusing